# Windows Shell Moves files in a folder that match a certain pattern

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, command-prompt

I want to accomplish the following unix function in Windows shell:

mv */FOLDER1/FOLDER2/* .

the pattern FOLDER1/FOLDER2 would always remain the same

Answer (score 0):

Look at `Move-Item`, the docs are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-6). An example use would be;

`Move-Item -Path C:\Temp -Destination C:\Logs`

They have more examples in the documentation linked.